# Add color categories to Outlook using GPO

Tags: group-policy, outlook

Using this template entry you can add color categories to Outlook users:
[image]

But I cannot find anywhere a description of the syntax.
Let's say I wanna add two categories with specific colors:

- MyCat1, Black
- MyCat2, Yellow

[image]

I know it should be a comma or semicolon separated list, but I cannot  nail it :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In setting `Administrative templates\Microsoft Outlook XXXX\Miscellaneous\Add new categories` you can only specify comma separeted list of new categories which will be added to the list of user categories.

Ability to specify the colors for the new categories through this setting **is not available**.

I guess the only affordable way - use [scripting API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff866465.aspx) for some automation.